# Suppress signals and emit it later

Tags: qt

I have got an object which state is control by user through `QDialog`. There are a lot of `QLineEdit`s, `QRadioButton`s and other stuff in the dialog window. I have created `slots` in the object and connected it with `signals` from widgets. Everythig works fine, and state of the object changes as soon as I press widget. Now I have added `ok` and `cancel` buttons and I want the object state to be changed only after I click `ok` button and not to be changed when I press `cancel` button. So, is it possible to catch signals from widgets and emit them when `ok` button is clicked or suppress them when `cancel` button is clicked.I am using `Qt 5.2.1`

Comment: In the slot of the Widgets e.g. LineEdit or QRadiobutton you have to store the States temporary. After a click on the Ok Button you can write the Data to persistent Storage or something like that. Cancel button discards all temporary data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can not do this easily. Also  I think solving this on signal levels is the wrong approach.

You should cache the values and set them to your object on ok (not on cancel); or you can read the values directly from the widgets and pass them to your object in the same way without caching.

Are you building a settings dialog?

Comment: yes, it is a settings dialog of a number of plots. When dialog is created, it reads parameters from the plots and with that values construct widgets. I don't want to read values from all widgets and apply them to plots, because in that case all plots will be redrawn. I want to redraw only that plots which parameters have been changed.

Comment: Then compare the new values with the plots' current values and set them only if changed. Best would be to build that value change check into the plot setter methods if possible.